# To construct a group with certain properties.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group with properties listed in the following.

(1) $G/G''\cong A_4$.

(2) $G/K\cong SL(2,3)$ where $K=F(G)$ is isomorphic to an extraspecial $3$-group of order $3^7$, $K/Z(K)$ is a $G$-chief factor.

(3) Let $P\in Syl_3(G)$. Then $P=KD$ where $D\cong C_{9}$ and $Z(P)=Z(K)=Z(G)$.

(4) All elements of order $3$ lie in $G'$.

**My question is: Does the group that I described here exist?**

The group I described here is too big to construct by using GAP (by myself).

Assume that group $G$ that I described exists.
Then $G/K$ acting irreducibly on a $GF(3)$-module $V:=K/Z(G)$.
So, by Clifford theory, $V$, as a $GF(3)[G'/K]$-module, equals $W\oplus Wx\oplus Wx^2$, where $W$ has dimension 2 and $o(x)=3$. (Otherwise, $V$ is an irreducible $GF(3)[G'/K]$-module, however, $G'/K\cong Q_8$ only has irreducible $GF(3)[G'/K]$-modules of dimension $1$ or $2$.)
To construct $G$, I first try to construct a group $T$ isomorphic to $G/Z(G)$, then I construct a factor group of schur covering group of $T$ with center a cyclic subgroup of order $3$.

Any explanation, references, suggestion and examples are appreciated.

Comment: It might be worth adding some context for why you want this group to exist, whether you expect it to exist (or expect it to _not_ exist) and why. As it stands this looks like a pretty strange collection of properties, and some context might also help guide the search for other (counter)examples that also answer whatever problem led you to care about such a group.

Comment: Why have two people voted to close this post? Does it really look like a straightforward homework question?

Comment: Presumably (4) should read "All elements of order 3 lie in G'."? Note also that $G/K = {\rm SL}(2,3)$ is not a Frobenius group.

Comment: In fact ${\rm SL}(2,3)$ does not have and irreducible $6$-dimensional representation over ${\mathbb F}_3$, so no such group exists.

Comment: Yes, I made some stupid mistakes and I corrected some of my mistakes. By checking the Brauer character table (for prime $3$) of $SL(2,3)$, there are only three Brauer characters and they have degrees 1, 2, 3.  For me, "$SL(2,3)$ does not have an irreducible 6-dimensional representation over $GF(3)$" means that $GF[3]$  is a splitting field of $SL(2,3)$ (maybe I made another mistake). Could you please explain more on why $SL(2,3)$ does not have an irreducible 6-dimensional representation over $GF(3)$? @DerekHolt

Comment: You can compute the irreducible representations of a finite group over a finite field using GAP or Magma, and there are indeed $3$ such representations of ${\rm SL}(2,3)$ over ${\mathbb F}_3$ of dimensions $1$ $2$ and $3$. The entries of the Brauer character table in characteristic $3$ are all integers, so the corresponding representations can all be written over ${\mathbb F}_3$.

Comment: Thanks very much for your explanation. Because, for each irreducible representations of $G=SL(2,3)$, their Schur index are all 1. For all $\varphi \in \mathrm{IBr}(G)$, let $\varphi^*$ be the trace function of simple module over a large field (for instance $GF(9)$), and we add every values of $\varphi^*$ in $GF(3)$ for all $\varphi \in \mathrm{IBr}(G)$ and write the field $E$. Then $E$ is a splitting field of $G$. However, $E=GF(3)$. So, $GF(3)$ is a splitting field of $G$. Is this your point? @DerekHolt